# How can I 'blink' the whole surface view

Tags: android

In my android application, I have a SurfaceView to show Camera Preview.
I got that to work.

But my question is how can I do a 'blink' effect on this SurfaceView, I would like to give user a visual aid when a photo is taken.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try adding a view wich is only a white background and animate it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by have an invisible black/white view on top of the surface view . when you wish to have the blink , show the view and use a handler to post a runnable after a very few ms , which will make the view invisible again.

you can also use alpha animations to make it look cooler.